# Classe anônima recebendo um valor através de uma função

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, funções, interface, eventos

Galera, é o seguinte, eu acabei me deparando com uma situação que eu não entendi bem como funciona.

Alguns objetos como por exemplo o componentes no Swing do Java, ou qualquer tipo de objetos de frameworks que possuem eventos, normalmente é possível adicionar um listener para o programador adicionar um método com sua própria ação para aquele evento, correto? Em Java é uma interface como parâmetro de uma função como por exemplo addEventListener(EventListener listener).

O que acontece é que quando o desenvolvedor quer associar um valor a esse listener, antes de fazer essa adição, ele pode criar uma classe que implemente a interface, e então criar os campos que quiser e manipular de sua forma na implementação dos métodos abstratos da interface, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
//Interface para o evento de uma ação de componentes do Swing do Java
public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {

    /**
     * Invoked when an action occurs.
     * @param e the event to be processed
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);

}
```

Seria possivel associar algum valor para manipular assim:

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private MeuObjeto objeto;

    public MyActionListener(MeuObject objeto) {
        this.objeto = objeto;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //ação personalizada com manipulação do objeto recebido aqui
    }
}
```

E então poderia utilizar a classe com a implementação da interface:

```
button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(objeto));
```

Porém eu fiz um teste de uma forma diferente, criando uma função que retorna uma classe anônima dessa interface, sem criar atributos, tipo:

```
    private ActionListener criarActionListener(Long id) {
        return new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Ação com o parâmetro id passado da função aqui
            }
        };
    }
```

e então poderia passar meu listener assim:

```
button.addEventListener(criarActionListener(id));
```

O propósito seria por exemplo, associar o id de um objeto de uma lista ou um banco de dados, e quando executar a ação do botão ou qualquer outro componente que se encaixe nesse modelo, eu nessa ação poder recuperar o objeto exato pelo id ou coisa assim. E o que acontece é que dessa forma dá certo, e o id fica associado, porém a classe é anônima e não possui um campo id explicitamente adicionado dentro dela, e mesmo assim funciona, como? Não entendo como a classe anônima consegue manter esse valor que na real foi passado por uma função sem realmente associar a alguma variavel no campo da classe.

Comment: Também não entendo os detalhes, mas sei que antes do Java 8 esse parâmetro `id` precisava ser declarado como `final` (ou seja, devia ocorrer algum tipo de substituição pelo valor constante que ficava fixado onde quer que fosse usado ao ser construída a classe anônima) e do Java 8 em diante não precisa mais (mas o efeito é o mesmo). Note que declarar a classe anônima diretamente onde vai ser usada e usar o `id` nela dá o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @Piovezan Não precisa que a variável tenha o modificador `final`, ela pode ser "effectively final": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

Comment: @hkotsubo Foi o que eu quis dizer com "o efeito é o mesmo". Antes do Java 8 tinha que ser explicitamente `final` como o sr. certamente sabe :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/4732544/2241463